# MySql and database connections in launch4j setup file

Tags: mysql, netbeans-8, launch4j

I have  prepared a setup file in launch-4j and its wrapped with jre bundle. It is working in another systems only if MySql is started and database is dumped in their systems. How can I include database in the code and how to execute it without localhost